# How to get the output of another material datablock via Python?

Tags: scripting, add-on, shader-nodes

Basically, I want the information that goes into the Shader Output...
[image]
...to be accessible from my custom node's output. Basically as if the material output were a group output, if that makes sense.

This is the code I have so far.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import ShaderNode, ShaderNodeTree
from bpy.props import PointerProperty

class SimpleCustomShaderNode(ShaderNode, ShaderNodeTree):
    bl_idname = 'CustomNodeType'
    bl_label = 'Simple Custom Shader Node'
    bl_icon = 'NODE'

    material: PointerProperty(
        name="Material",
        description="Material datablock",
        type=bpy.types.Material
    )

    def init(self, context):
        self.outputs.new('NodeSocketShader', 'Material Output')
        self.outputs.new('NodeSocketShader', 'Volume Output')
        self.outputs.new('NodeSocketVector', 'Displacement Output')

    def draw_buttons(self, context, layout):
        layout.prop(self, 'material', text='')

    def draw_label(self):
        return 'Simple Custom Shader'


    def update(self):
        nodes = self.material.node_tree.nodes
        material_output = next((node for node in nodes if node.type == 'OUTPUT_MATERIAL'), None)
        if material_output:
            # Access the inputs of the "Material Output" node
            for input in material_output.inputs:
                # Check if the input is linked
                if input.is_linked:
                    # Get the linked node
                    linked_socket = input.links[0].from_socket
        
        self.outputs['Material Output'].default_value = linked_socket.get()



def add_node_item(self, context):
    self.layout.operator("node.add_node", text=bl_label, icon="INFO").type = "CustomNodeType"

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleCustomShaderNode)
    bpy.types.NODE_MT_add.append(add_node_item)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleCustomShaderNode)
    bpy.types.NODE_MT_add.remove(add_node_item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

The best I've been able to glean is that this should be done within the `update()` method, but I'm not even sure about that. The code within `update()` probably isn't quite right either, but it's the best my API documentation sleuthing and ChatGPT questioning was able to come up with.

Any advice?

Comment: You can't, because Python code is evaluated on CPU while gathering the data for GPU. Then it is sent to the GPU, along with the shading tree compiled to a shading language, which is then run on the GPU - the "pipeline" of Blender doesn't allow to you to evaluate a shader partially, to then return to CPU and e.g. run some Python code to process it further. There's no vanilla node system (shading, compositor, geonodes) that would allow you to read the contents of input socket or write to the output socket.

Comment: Ah. Well, that's a shame. Thank you so much for the explanation!!